# Good cross browser javascript compatibility/enhancement library?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, standards

Apparently I have lost all my google skills. I can not find any good results for javascript libraries that attempt to cross-browser standardize javascript and provide small enhancements.

I AM NOT looking for a full framework like jQuery, Prototype, etc... even though they do this type of thing on some level. I'm talking about language/available function standardization only, no DOM stuff. Just a good cross browser library that ensures availability of all the standard stuff (array map, reduce, etc..), support for stuff like Date.toISOString() in IE 6/7/8, etc... I already know about ie7.js, ie8.js and ie9.js, but they don't exactly fit the bill.

So what else is out there?

**UPDATE**
Just to be clear, here is the type of thing said library would do (all crossbrowser, with native fallbacks obviously):

- Date.toISOstring support
- Array.map, Array.each, Array.filter, Array.reduce support
- Shallow/Deep object cloning
- etc...

Comment: Good question. I guess nobody really ever bothers with that sort of library since we have jQuery.

Comment: I'd guess you have to say why doesn't jQuery meet your needs so we could have a better idea of what you're looking for that's different than jQuery.

Comment: Im kinda starting to think there isnt anything really good out there. To be honest I asked the question cause im thinking about taking it on as a project.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel on this one. If someone is going to spend the time to learn a cross-browser library, they are going to want one that also has the ability to be more fully-functional, such as jQuery.

Comment: @jfriend00: ...I already use jquery, its great. But it does nothing for standardization of things such as a fallback Date.toISOString implementation. Yes, it has array functions like $.fn.map, $.fn.each, etc... but that doesn't integrate natively to object prototypes, which would be much nicer in my opinion

Comment: @Justin:  Well thats kind of the point. There is still discrepancy in object prototypes between browsers. A standardization library would fix that, and eliminate the need to learn a framework's way of doing things that should just be available natively, not introduce something entirely new (with the exceptions of any enhancements, but DOM is out of scope so I dont see jQuery functionality really being duplicated in many places)

Comment: Then, I'd suggest you add to your question a list of what you're looking for beyond the three you've mentioned and maybe you'll be more likely to get responses that match what you're looking for.

Comment: @jfriend00 jQuery isn't a compatibility layer, it's a framework. arguably, these are separate concerns, and shouldn't be conflated in a single library (or at least not in the same layer of the library!)

Comment: @Michael - you're reading the question AFTER it had been clarified and after that clarification, I provided the answer below that was accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Array extensions** (LastElement, InsertAt, InsertRange, Remove, RemoveAt, RemoveRange, Clear, Contains, Equals, Copy, Append, Merge, Search, Filter): 
http://programmingsolution.net/post/JavaScript-Array-Extension.aspx

**Array extensions**: (copy, forEach, find, findAll, contains, distinct, min, max, first, last, sortAscending, sortDescending, randomize, count, except, intersect, average, sum, union, safePush, getRandom, insertAt, remove): http://www.thegrubbsian.com/2009/01/25/useful-javascript-extensions

**Date object extensions** - datejs.js: (today, compare, between, compareTo, equals, isAFter, isBefore, isLeapYear, parse, parseExact, validateDay, validateHour, validateMonth, validateMinute, validateSecond, validateYear, add, addSeconds, addMinutes, addHours, addDays, addYears, addWeeks, addMonths, clone, getWeek, getISOWeek, setWeek, toISOString): http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation

**copy, deepCopy, clone** - http://oranlooney.com/deep-copy-javascript/

Comment: You should just be using UnderscoreJS...it's much better than any of the options out there, doesn't mess with native objects, and its source code is easy to read and extend.

Answer (score 11):

I find [UnderscoreJS](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) very useful for looping/sorting/querying, array manipulation, map/reduce etc:

It doesn't have date time related functions. For datetime parsing, there is [dateJS](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/)

Comment: Should have remembered underscore, ive seen its name showing up more lately.  Out of curiosity, why do all these libraries seem to stay away from just modifying the prototype chain. They never come out and say it, but the impression is that they think its a bad thing.

Comment: Yes. Modifying the prototypical chain is not a good idea especailly if you're a library. You never know what else could be used on the page and you certyainly don't want to override something accidentally.

Comment: What prototypejs dared to do was decorate various Object, but thr cud some hard line issues when the developer isn't aware of certain outliers. UnderscoreJS is surely the way to go to provide all basic utilities we want apart from DOM Manipulations. jQuery core is not that heavy if only used for DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 5):

If you're only looking for JS constructs without any DOM bloat, you may be interested in the ES5 shim: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

It ensures most ES5 features to a reasonable degree.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that one. Definitely on the right track.

Comment: It looks like https://code.google.com/p/ddr-ecma5/ is more thoroughly tested to ensure compatibility, but does basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PassJS](http://passjs.sourceforge.net/), an arising JS library.